# Override MessageBodyReader in Jersey to wrap deserialization process

Tags: json, rest, serialization, jersey, jackson

I have a restful service which uses Grizzly, Jersey, Jackson stack. If I provide bad input values in the request for example: a random string instead of UUID then Jackson throws an invalid format or unrecognized property exception. For security purposes, I have added exception mappers for most generic exceptions to hide exception details. But for this very specific case where if user provides bad data and deserialization fails, I want to provide user feedback with why calls are failing.

I thought that if I can wrap the deserialization call from Jersey to Jackson then I can throw a custom exception with appropriate data and add a mapper for my custom exception.

So, I created a new class which overrides JacksonJaxbJsonProvider and add the wrapper code to the readFrom.

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD) // NOTE: required to support "non-standard" JSON variants
@Produces(MediaType.WILDCARD)
public class JacksonJaxbJsonProviderOverride extends JacksonJaxbJsonProvider {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JacksonJaxbJsonProviderOverride.class);

  @Override
  public Object readFrom(
      Class<Object> type,
      Type genericType,
      Annotation[] annotations,
      MediaType mediaType,
      MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
      InputStream entityStream)
      throws IOException {
    try {
      return super.readFrom(type, genericType, annotations, mediaType, httpHeaders, entityStream);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new ObjectDeserializationException(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

I also registered this class with Jersey as follows:

```
// Use our JacksonProducer mapper for serialization/deserialization
JacksonJaxbJsonProviderOverride jaxbJsonProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProviderOverride();
jaxbJsonProvider.setMapper(JacksonProducer.getMapperForJaxb());
resourceConfig.register(jaxbJsonProvider);
```

But the call for deserialization does not hit the overrides. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.UUID from String value 'foo': not a valid textual representation, problem: UUID has to be represented by the standard 36-char representation
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@43277af; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.oracle.opc.nimbula.foo.models.api.BackupInput["backupConfigurationId"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:55) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.weirdStringException(DeserializationContext.java:907) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.FromStringDeserializer.deserialize(FromStringDeserializer.java:136) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:258) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1470) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:912) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:810) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$lReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:874) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:271) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:94) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourcDispatcherProvider.java:160) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:384) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:224) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.j) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571) [program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: UUID has to be represented by the standard 36-char representation
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UUIDDeserializer._badFormat(UUIDDeserializer.java:75) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UUIDDeserializer._deserialize(UUIDDeserializer.java:40) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UUIDDeserializer._deserialize(UUIDDeserializer.java:11) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.FromStringDeserializer.deserialize(FromStringDeserializer.java:122) ~[program-0.3.0-20160226101624.jar:na]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the full stacktrace. Can you post the whole thing.

Comment: As an aside, the error responses are sent by ExceptionMappers. Jackson comes with one for JsonMappingException and JsonParseException. You can _not_ register these and register your own

Comment: @peeskillet I added full stack trace. ExceptionMappers won't work because I am using Jackson for serialization/deserialization at other places. If I add exception mapper for every serialize/deserialize, I might leak information to the user. I want to tell Jersey that only during its deserialization, if it throws an error, then wrap it in a custom exception for which I can add an exception mapper.

Comment: There might be a different way of doing this.

Comment: configure( DeserializationFeature.WRAP_EXCEPTIONS, false );
maybe this could help... https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features